# Asterisk incoming call DID question (number dialed)

Tags: asterisk

I am setting up a new Asterisk system at a hosted Asterisk provider using 1.4.38, moving from a self-hosted version 1.2.  Whereas before I could do: 
[incoming]
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,1,DoSomething

Now, it appears the incoming context will only get properly called if it is:
[incoming]
exten => s,1,DoSomething

How do I determine what number was dialed in this scenario?  We have dozens of numbers and I need to be able to know which was called to route correctly...

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Turns out it was a SIP configuration issue...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pattern. I have this line in a running asterisk instance:

exten => 5858876463,1,Set(__FROM_DID=${EXTEN})

However, to answer your question, you can use the ${EXTEN} variable to decide what number was called. E.g.

exten => s,1,SomeScript(${EXTEN})

Comment: If this would do, then his above example should work as well. 
It sounds like a problem with the way the call is signaled. It might not have the information or might not have it where it is expected. 

If access on the hosted system allows it, I would activate sip debugging to see what is actually transmitted. Then match the invite or populate a variable with whatever Variable has the DID number in it, This can then Goto a context that has the inbound numbers in it.