# AMI Command to check which DID was called (Asterisk)

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

Need help, please assist me!

I need a command that would let us know which DID is the incoming call landed on, eventually we would then pass this collected info to phpagi and AMI. I was looking at

```
manager show command status
```

Was looking at following link but did not understand as how could I use it with AMI.
[Asterisk incoming call DID question (number dialed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515410/asterisk-incoming-call-did-question-number-dialed)

Can someone please guide me as to if I am in the right direction, and what should I be looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way ask something like that via ami. Except maybe ami "command core show channel channel_name_here"

You need use dialplan or AGI or track AMI events (new extension event) to see whats gooing on.

Comment: Yes! In agi i am looking at agi->request['agi_dnid']; to get me the required data and then be able to pass it on.

Answer (score 0):

In agi i am looking at $agi->request['agi_dnid']; to get me the required data and then be able to pass it on.